# How to Change Folder Icons visibility mode?

Tags: icons, privileges

I am using Ubuntu 11.10. The visibility mode of Folder Icons in my main drives are getting changed without my access on them.

Sometimes they are showing as a folders and some times they are visible as a text files, but they are actually folders. Can I know where to change the settings for these?

please rectify my problem.

Comment: Please use Meta for questions related to the site of itself.

Comment: which folders are changed? Usually folders which you dont have permissions to execute (means look into) may be shown with a file icon.

Comment: all folders in all the storage devices.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can see visible as a text files,Because You can't owner your files.

you can see here.https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

See also

```
chmod

chown
```

You can try .I can solve this way.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in home directory go up (on the bar with clock) you have the menu is active when cursor is there, go to editing and then preferences, there are some option for folders and files.